# SwiftUI paged scroll view issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I'm trying to create an animation for a scrollView to overlap a new page over an image. The image will cover most of the screen and shouldn't move and the text should swipe over it.
The animation works fine but when I scroll the page, if the text is too long and can't be encapsulated in half of the screen, the top part hides under the safe area. Any ideas how to solve it?

```swift
GeometryReader(content: { geometry in
                    ZStack(content: {
                        Color(.blue)
                            .ignoresSafeArea()
                        AsyncImage(
                            url: URL(string: pod.hdurl)!,
                            content: { image in
                                image.resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .clipped()
                            },
                            placeholder: {
                                ProgressView()
                            })
                    })
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 6, leading: 22, bottom: 6, trailing: 22))
                    .frame(
                        width: geometry.size.width,
                        height: geometry.size.height * 0.9,
                        alignment: .center
                    )
                    
                    Spacer ()
                    
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(content: {
                            Group {
                                Color(.clear)
                            }
                            .frame(
                                width: geometry.size.width,
                                height: geometry.size.height * 0.9,
                                alignment: .center
                            )
                            
                            ZStack(content: {
                                Color(.red)
                                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                                VStack(content: {
                                    Text(pod.title)
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .foregroundStyle(.primary)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    
                                    Text(pod.explanation + pod.explanation)
                                        .font(.body)
                                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                })
                            })
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22))
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 22, bottom: 6, trailing: 22))
                            .scrollTransition { content, phase in
                                content
                                    .opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8)
                                    .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8)
                                    .blur(radius: phase.isIdentity ? 0 : 2)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
                    .padding([.top], 1)
                })
```

[image: Before scrolling]

[image: After scroll]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the top of the descriptive text with the red background is not showing when the text is very long. So the user is not aware that the text is available for scrolling, even though scrolling works.

I think there are a couple of small issues.

0. It's not an error, but you are making the code more complicated than it needs to be by specifying `content` for the containers. I would suggest, it is simpler to use trailing closures, which is also how Apple does it in all the examples you will find. So the snippets below have been updated in this way. You might also like to consider using the built-in formatting provided by Xcode: select the code and press Ctrl/I.
1. Inside the `GeometryReader`, you have more than one `View`, but there is no layout defined for these views. I would suggest using another top-level `ZStack` for the items inside the `GeometryReader`. Also, the `Spacer` is not needed:

```swift
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack { // <- ADDED
            ZStack {
                // content as before
            }
            // modifiers as before

            // Spacer () // not needed

            ScrollView {
                // content as before
            }
            // modifiers as before
        }
    }
}
```

2. You need to specify `.top` as the anchor for the scale effect

```
.scrollTransition { content, phase in
    content
        .opacity(phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8)
        .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1.0 : 0.8, anchor: .top) // anchor added
        .blur(radius: phase.isIdentity ? 0 : 2)
}
```

With these changes, it works for me.